# itext could not parse bootstrap.css

Tags: java, itext

**code:**

```
package test.test1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.Pipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.CssFile;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.StyleAttrCSSResolver;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.Tags;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CSSResolver;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.end.PdfWriterPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipelineContext;

public class Table {


    File oFile = new File("c:\\test\\1.pdf");
    public static Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    PdfWriter writer =null;


        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {  


             PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("c:\\test\\1.pdf"));
            document.open();
            HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
            htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
            CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
            InputStream cssIS = Thread.currentThread()
                    .getContextClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("css\\index.css");

            CssFile cssfile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(cssIS);
            InputStream cssIS1 = Thread.currentThread()
                    .getContextClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("css\\bootstrap.css");
            CssFile cssfile1 = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(cssIS1);
            cssResolver.addCss(cssfile);
            cssResolver.addCss(cssfile1);
            Pipeline<?> pipeline =

                new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver,

                    new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext,

                        new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));

            XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,new FileInputStream("resources\\index.html"),
                    new FileInputStream("resources\\css\\bootstrap.css"));
              document.close();
             System.out.println( "PDF Created!" );
        }
}
```

**Description:**
I am trying to generate html to pdf file using itext library in java.

**Input:** index.html, bootstrap.css,index.css

**output:** pdf file

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100%"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:422)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.FontSizeTranslator.getFontSize(FontSizeTranslator.java:186)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.FontSizeTranslator.translateFontSize(FontSizeTranslator.java:165)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.AbstractTagProcessor.startElement(AbstractTagProcessor.java:120)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline.open(HtmlPipeline.java:105)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker.startElement(XMLWorker.java:103)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.startElement(XMLParser.java:372)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.state.TagEncounteredState.process(TagEncounteredState.java:104)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parseWithReader(XMLParser.java:237)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:215)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:176)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(XMLWorkerHelper.java:222)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(XMLWorkerHelper.java:226)
    at test.test1.Table.main(Table.java:160)
```

so here i think font getting problem here,please tell me what exactly i do?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the CSS is not supported by itext's XML worker.

Since bootstrap contains very advanced CSS, this is pretty much doomed...

You'll need to write your own CSS file with very limited styling compared to bootstrap

Edit: 
Updated link to supported css:
https://wiki.base22.com/btg/itext-5-css-properties-support-when-using-html-to-pdf-features-147327746.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: broken link in the comment should not provided.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!